# What kind of plant is this purple plant?

Tags: identification

I took a cutting from someone's houseplant and rooted it and planted it, but I don't know what kind of plant it is.  It's doing well outside but I'll move it inside when cold weather hits.  The leaves are almond shaped and I believe it had flowers when I had it in the house.  Someone said it's an Oyster plant but the pictures I looked at don't look like those.  The leaves are purple and look like they should be fuzzy but instead they are kind of thick and rubbery.  Any idea?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Tradescantia purpurea. It's not possible to tell how tall your plant actually is from your photo, but this plant only gets around 7 inches tall and tends to spread sideways, eventually trailing or sprawling. It is frost tender, and can be used as a border or container plant during the summer months. Image and information on plant care here https://www.gardenia.net/plant/Tradescantia-pallida-Purple-Heart

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much.  Mystery solved.  I love this plant, almost impossible to kill it not that I have tried.  Very easy to root cuttings too.  I might give them as Christmas gifts this year, lol.  And you are right, it's about 10 iches and looks like it will grow as a vine.  I'll read all about it now and thanks for the link.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you're happy with it, otherwise it remains open...